# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 251: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a small project.and i want to open a url.i tried with this

```
url = 'http://www.ygdy8.net/html/gndy/dyzz/index.html'
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read() 

pat = re.compile('<div class="title_all"><h1><front color=#008800>.*?</a>>   </front></h1></div>'+ '(.*?)<td height="25" align="center" bgcolor="#F4FAE2"> ',re.S)
txt = ''.join(pat.findall(content))
```

but this give me the error

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

then i tried with

```
txt = ''.join(pat.findall(content.decode()))
```

but there also an error

```
    txt = ''.join(pat.findall(content.decode()))
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 251: invalid start byte
```

i looked for the answer but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: have you tried `content.decode("latin-1")` ?

Comment: I deleted my answer. `latin-1` works but you really have to get the header info to know the encoding. one of the answers of the linked duplicate question explained that.

Comment: The header implies `content.decode('gb2312',errors='ignore')` should work. That being said, I don't think your regex will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header implies content.decode('gb2312',errors='ignore') should work.

```
>>> content.find(b'charset')
226
>>> content[226:226 + 20]
b'charset=gb2312">\r\n<t'
```

However, your regex certainly will NOT work. You have `front` instead of `font`. Perhaps you wanted the following:

```
>>> pat = re.compile(r'<div class="title_all"><h1><font color=#008800>.*?</a>></font></h1></div>'+ r'(.*?)<td height="25" align="center" bgcolor="#F4FAE2"> ',re.S)
```

This catches the table stuff between the two pieces, as far as I can tell.

```
>>> txt = ''.join(pat.findall(content.decode('gb2312',errors='ignore')))
>>> print(txt[:500])

<div class="co_content8">
<ul>

<td height="220" valign="top"> <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tbspan" style="margin-top:6px">
<tr> 
<td height="1" colspan="2" background="/templets/img/dot_hor.gif"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td width="5%" height="26" align="center"><img src="/templets/img/item.gif" width="18" height="17"></td>
<td height="26">
    <b>

        <a href="/html/gndy/dyzz/20160920/52002.html" class="ulink">2016年井柏然杨颖《微微一笑很倾城》HD国语中字</a>
    </b>
<
>>> pat.pattern
'<div class="title_all"><h1><font color=#008800>.*?</a>></font></h1></div>(.*?)<td height="25" align="center" bgcolor="#F4FAE2"> '
>>>
```